# Why Symfony2 doesn't have/like models?

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony, model

I was looking for models in Symfony2 structure and bundles but there are none.

What is the reason Symfony2 do not have models?

Is MVC the wrong way to go?

I am just curious because I know that CodeIgniter in fact doesn't need to use models too. You can place everything in controllers or even in model in some scenarios ;).

Could somebody explain it more in depth?

Comment: I switched from CodeIgniter to Symfony and that was one of the best decisions I made. CodeIgniter has some kind of Model system: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html .. but it's not the usual ORM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Fabien Potencier, the former of Symfony2, does not think Models belongs in Symfony. That's why he called it a HTTP framework instead. See also this article he wrote: ["What is Symfony2?"](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2)

> [...] you should know that Symfony2 is really about providing the tools for the Controller part, the View part, but not the Model part. It's up to you to create your model by hand or use any other tool, like an ORM. Of course, tight integration exists for the most well known ORMs like Doctrine2 and Propel; but they are optional dependencies. The Symfony2 core features do not and will never rely on any ORM.

---

The Doctrine2 ORM uses repositories to take over the control of mapping databases to a class. If you want to have custom methods in your repository, you can [create your own repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). That means that a Repository can be seen as a sort of model.

Comment: Doctrine2 ORM is an awesome project and I'm glad Symfony Framework Standard Edition comes with it.

Answer (score 2):

Because they didn't want to.

Tough answer, but there is no set in stone way to program. There are many different methodologies and you can choose to follow them if you wish, but nobody is making you. In this case, the developers for Symfony2 decided models weren't necessary.

That doesn't mean MVC is wrong. I own a sedan, but if you own an SUV, does that mean you're doing it wrong? Just a different way to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no "models" in proper MVC. Model is a layer. Just like presentation layer (which contains controllers, views and templates).

What you should be looking for instead are: services, mappers and domain objects. Those are the more common parts of model layer.

Comment: With your logic there is also no controller, just "controller layer". Think about that. ;)

Comment: @Derfder , controllers are part of presentation layer. Which word made you confused ?